# Can Not Integrate Google Analytics in my Android app

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to track all my users activities using Google Analytics in my Android Mobile App. I add libGoogleAnalytics.jar in my Build Path, create an account in Google analytics (so I have my UA-XXXXXXXX-Y number).Here is how I initialize the tracker and try to track the current Activity:

```
    tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
    tracker.setDebug(true);
    tracker.setDryRun(false);
    tracker.startNewSession("UA-XXXXXXXX-Y", MyActivity.this);

    tracker.trackPageView("/MainScreen");
    tracker.dispatch();
```

I also add needed permitions in my AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
...
```

How you can see I enable the debugging in order to verify my configuration. And everything in debug log looks fine for me:

```
10-28 17:43:59.233: VERBOSE/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(11024): Called dispatch
10-28 17:43:59.233: VERBOSE/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(11024): Sending 1 hits to dispatcher
10-28 17:43:59.233: INFO/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(11024): Host: www.google-analytics.com
10-28 17:43:59.233: INFO/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(11024): User-Agent: GoogleAnalytics/1.5.1 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; en-gb; GT-I9100 Build/IML74K)
10-28 17:43:59.233: INFO/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(11024): GET /__utm.gif?utmwv=4.9.1ma&utmn=155573506&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=480x800&utmul=en-GB&utmp=%2FMainScreen&utmac=UA-xxxxxxxx-y&utmcc=__utma%3D1.1239100675.1351436696.1351436696.1351436696.1%3B&utmht=1351439039180&utmqt=59 HTTP/1.1
10-28 17:43:59.348: VERBOSE/GoogleAnalyticsTracker(11024): HTTP Response Code: 200
```

And my problem is that nothing is displayed in my Analytics Account. So nothing was tracked! The Real - Time statistics also show 0 and No Data.

Anybody faced with something like that?????

Comment: How long has it bean since you used it? You may want to [give it some time](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/frequently-google-analytics-update-33562.html).

Comment: @Angel Tsvetkov: I face the same problem. Still don't understand why there is no data in Google Analytics.

Comment: I did 3 different accounts and wait for more then 2 days for each of them to receive any data.

Comment: i am also facing same problem created two accounts still no data show on dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SOLUTION]
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/?hl=bg

Migrate to the new beta version of the Google Analytics based on Easy Tracker and you will have pretty good tracking of user interaction.

That solve my problem and everything works fine now!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using automatic dispatch method, I never had a problem with it and got report in maximum an hour.

Analytics report screen by default doesn't show current days reports, don't forget to select today for enddata while checking your reports.

(you don't need to dispatch method when you give an interval like example)

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/devguide#samples

```
// ...alternatively, the tracker can be started with a dispatch interval (in seconds).
tracker.startNewSession("UA-YOUR-ACCOUNT-HERE", 20, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

It takes 24 hours for data to come through to google analytics web interface!